# How to make ItemsSource Type-ignorant?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, drag-and-drop

I am working on a Drag/Drop mechanism for a WPF DatagGrid. So far I have this working:

```
 protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && Sections.Count > 1)
        {
            var row = UIHelpers.TryFindFromPoint<DataGridRow>(Dg, e.GetPosition(Dg));
            var item = row.Item;
            var sourceIndex = Sections.IndexOf((Section) item);

            // Package the data.
            DataObject data = new DataObject();
            data.SetData(typeof(int),sourceIndex);
            // Inititate the drag-and-drop operation.
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, data,  DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }

 protected override void OnDrop( DragEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDrop(e);
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;

        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(int)))
        {
            var row = UIHelpers.TryFindFromPoint<DataGridRow>(Dg, e.GetPosition(Dg));
            if (row == null)
                return;
            var item = row.Item;
            var targetIndex = Sections.IndexOf((Section) item);

            var sourceIndex = (int) e.Data.GetData(typeof(int));
            if (sourceIndex != targetIndex)
            {
                var list = (IList<Section>)Dg.ItemsSource;
                if (targetIndex == -1)
                {
                    list.Add(list[sourceIndex]);
                    list.RemoveAt(sourceIndex);
                }
                else
                {
                    list.Insert(targetIndex, list[sourceIndex]);
                    if (sourceIndex < targetIndex)
                        list.RemoveAt(sourceIndex);
                    else
                        list.RemoveAt(sourceIndex + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Sections is the ItemsSource of the DataGrid.

I would like to get this code Type-ignorant, so I can use it for other types than Section.

This won't work:

```
var sourceIndex = (int) ((List<object>) Dg.ItemsSource).FindIndex(a => a == item);
```

What would?

Comment: why that last bit won't work?

Comment: The problem here is your Sections variable, how do you think to match the good collection according the generic type ?

Comment: The message I get is:Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[drag.Section]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]'.

Comment: The type of the `ItemsSource` property is `IEnumerable` so you could cast to this type but then you won't be able to add any items to it. So what's your type constraints here? How do you know that the `ItemsSource` is currently set to an `IList<Section>` or some other type of list?

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast a collection into a `List`. Conveniently `IEnumerable` has a `Cast<T>` method which returns an `IEnumerable<T>` collection. and more conveniently **linq** methods are accessible from an  `IEnumerable<T>` object.

```
using System.Linq;
```

So in order to make it type-ignorant you can cast each element into `object` type.

```
object test = Dg.ItemsSource.Cast<object>().First(a => a == item);
```

But only `List` has `IndexOf` method so calling `ToList` enables us to find the index of an item:

```
var sourceIndex = Dg.ItemsSource.Cast<object>().ToList().IndexOf(item);
```